# Fixed column AND header on a table with both scroll

Tags: html, css, angular, html-table

I am on a project with Angular 5 and I am trying to have a table within and a vertical and horizontal scroll (with fixed left column and header), the vertical scroll works but not the horizontal one, even worse my  inside  is displayed in two lines.
My number of columns is also a variable and I wish that table takes 100% width. How do I achieve 100% table width?

My code :

css:

```
.table-tendency thead, .table-tendency tbody,.table-tendency tr,.table-tendency td, .table-tendency th { display: block; }

.table-tendency tr:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  clear: both;
}

.table-tendency thead td {
   height: 50px;
   font-weight: normal;

 }

.table-tendency tbody {
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.table-tendency {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.table-tendency thead td {
  width: 16.4% ;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.table-tendency tbody td {
  width: 16.6% ;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
```

HTML

```
        <div class=" table-responsive marge" *ngIf="selectedForecastSection.name !== '' && showTendencies">
          <table class="table table-striped table-tendency">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td> {{'Year' | translate}}</td>
                    <td  *ngFor="let tendencyPeriod of tendencyPeriods"> {{tendencyPeriod.name}}</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let year of years" >
                    <td class="yearColumn"> {{year}}</td>
                    <td   *ngFor="let tendencyPeriod of tendencyPeriods"> 
                        <span  [ngStyle]="setFont(dataFilter(year, tendencyPeriod.id))">    {{dataFilter(year, tendencyPeriod.id).anyVehicleFlow | number:'1.2-2'}}
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: did you ever get a resolution for this, Tom?